# Git push password mismatched

Tags: git, ubuntu, passwords

Ubuntu reloading system, git push/pull password is mismatched.
I just create git repository in local.

$git clone git@10.5.41.37:/home/D-disk/test/.git

Cloning into 'test'...

Password:

Password:

Password:

git@10.5.41.37's password:

Received disconnect from 10.5.41.37: 2: Too many authentication failures for git

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received disconnect from 10.5.41.37: 2: Too many authentication failures for git

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

just adduser git account